# Write to subdir in Zip? Using java.util.zip. ZipEntry.putNextEntry()

Tags: java, zip, subdirectory

So i created a zip and created a new sub folder in the zip file by creating a zip entry that ends in "\". How would i write to the subfolder?

My problem is i have a putnextEntry call on my ZipOutputStream in a for loop so after the folder gets created i then jump into a for loop where the different zip files are written. But they are written at the same level as the subdir within the zip.

What i think is happening is because i use putNextEntry with the first actual zip(not dir) entry it is closing the subfolder and writing to the root of the zip. Any ideas?

Code below

```
private int endprocess() {
        try {
            zipFolder(ripPath, zipOutputPath, "rips");
            //zipFolder(destPDFfiles, zipOutputPath, "pdfs");
            this.returnCode = 0;
            //log.debug ( "Accumulator count: " + acount);
            log.debug("Equivest count: " + ecount);
            //log.debug ( "Assoc count: " + scount);
            processEndOfEnvelope();
        } catch (Exception reportException) {
            log.logError("Caught exception in creating.");
            reportException.printStackTrace();
            this.returnCode = 15;
        }

        return (this.returnCode);

    }
    public static void zipFolder(String srcFolder, String dest, String outputFolder){
        try{
            ZipOutputStream zos = null;
            FileOutputStream fos = null;
            fos = new FileOutputStream(dest + "\\newzip.zip");
            zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos);
            addFolderToZip(srcFolder, zos, outputFolder);
            zos.flush();
            zos.close();
        }catch(IOException e){
            log.logError("**********************");
            log.logError("IO Exception occurred");
            log.logError(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void addFileToZip(String srcFile, ZipOutputStream zos, String outputFolder){
        try {
            File folder = new File(srcFile);
            if (folder.isDirectory()) {
                addFolderToZip(srcFile, zos, outputFolder);
            } else {
                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int length;
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(srcFile);
                ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry("C:\\AWDAAV\\zip\\newzip.zip\\" + outputFolder + "\\" + folder.getName());
                zos.putNextEntry(ze);
                while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.logError("**********************");
            log.logError("Exception occurred");
            log.logError(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void addFolderToZip(String srcFolder, ZipOutputStream zos, String outputFolder){
        try{
            File folder = new File(srcFolder);
            zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(outputFolder + "\\"));
            for(String fileName : folder.list()){
                addFileToZip(srcFolder + "\\" + fileName, zos, outputFolder);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            log.logError("**********************");
            log.logError("Exception occurred");
            log.logError(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a look at your code and i think the ZIP API works just as you think.

Only you had some logic errors with the path names.
You need to convert the path names from the local names to the relative locations in the zip file.
Maybe you got confused somewhere in that area.

Here is my suggestion:

File: org/example/Main.java

```
package org.example;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        MyZip myZip = new MyZip();
        Path sourcePath = Paths.get("C:/Users/David/Desktop/a");
        Path targetPath = Paths.get("C:/Users/David/Desktop/zip/out.zip");
        Path zipPath = Paths.get("tadaa");
        myZip.zipFolder(sourcePath, targetPath.toFile(), zipPath);
    }

}
```

**Update: Explanation of variables in main method**

- The `sourcePath` is a directory which content you want to include in the zip archive.
- The `targetPath` is the output path of the zip file. For example the new zip file will be created at exactly that location.
- The `zipPath` is the subdirectory within the zip directory where your content from `sourcePath` will be placed. This variable may also be set to `null`. If it is `null` the `sourcePath` will be put in the root of the new zip archive.

File: org/example/MyZip.java

```
package org.example;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.DirectoryStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import java.util.zip.ZipOutputStream;

public class MyZip {

    public void zipFolder(Path base, File dest, Path zipFolder) throws IOException {
        try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);
                ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fos)) {
            addFolderToZip(base.getParent(), base, zos, zipFolder);
        }
    }

    private void addFolderToZip(Path base, Path currentFolder, ZipOutputStream zos, Path zipFolder) throws IOException {
        try (DirectoryStream<Path> stream = Files.newDirectoryStream(currentFolder)) {
            for(Path path : stream) {
                Path relativePath = base != null ? base.relativize(path) : path;
                Path pathInZip = zipFolder != null ? zipFolder.resolve(relativePath) : relativePath;
                if(path.toFile().isDirectory()) {
                    zos.putNextEntry(new ZipEntry(pathInZip.toString() + "/"));
                    // recurse to sub directories
                    addFolderToZip(base, path, zos, zipFolder);
                } else {
                    addFileToZip(path, pathInZip, zos);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void addFileToZip(Path sourcePath, Path pathInZip, ZipOutputStream zos) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        try (FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(sourcePath.toFile())) {
            ZipEntry ze = new ZipEntry(pathInZip.toString());
            zos.putNextEntry(ze);
            while ((length = fis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                zos.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Im a little confused about what the zipPath variable holds. When does the zip file actually get created? Should the targetPath point to the sub-directory within the zip?

Comment: I added an explanation of all the variables in the main method to my answer. Also you may just copy and paste the code into a java project, and run it to see what it does. Of course you must change the paths i hard-coded in the main method.

Comment: Ok, perfect solution. I appreciate your help. I made it a static class with static method so that i dont have to instatiate MyZip so it is more like a helper class. The only other issue i am having is that when i run this more than once it is overwriting my zip. So i can only create 1 subdir in the Zip. I believe it has something to do with my initialization of my FileOutputStream. I will take a look and let you know if i figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

ZipEntry.setLevel(filepath[in your case, \folder]);

Comment: There is no setLevel method on the ZipEntry class. This is sort of what i am looking for if it actually worked.

Comment: not in ZipEntry, but there is in ZipOutputStream, I think if you set the path during the stream initialization, you should be able to run any information into that level

Comment: the .level method in the ZipOutputStream class is to set compression level. I have set the path in a FileOutputStream but the problem is that i only create the FileOutputStream once to create the .zip file. From there i write to a folder inside the .zip directory.

Comment: wouldn't the .level fix that issue for you? or is it resetting?

Comment: No the .level sets the compression level. You pass in an int.

Comment: hmm, honestly, I think David has it, it does't appear to be logically flawed, but, it could just be that I'm naive...